# Change "Select" choice in dropdown list to not a choice

Tags: 2010, infopath, properties, dropdown

I have a drop down list field and it's a required field, but I don't want the select default choice to be a choice. How do I accomplish this in Infopath?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the list box choices to have a blank value as the default choice..just delete the "select..." display name and leave that and the value column blank.  Then, under the Validation group, make sure to check the 'Cannot be blank' checkbox.  That should do the trick.